# Schedule Internet access for Mac users

Tags: osx, internet

I hate to admit this, but I always lose self-control on surfing the Internet. So, is there a OS X app to limit a user's surfing time?

For example, user can just surf the internet for an hour a day, after utilizing an hour, he should not surf anymore.

Application required for OS X.

---

What I am looking for is not a parent control software, you will need another user (**Parents**) , what I am looking for is an app like **[SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com/index.html)**, you don't need another user to supervise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified, whether you want a Premium or a Free software, so if you are looking for a Premium software, than try [Family Protector (Mac Parental Control Software)](http://www.intego.com/mac-parental-control-software).

[image]

Features which matches your requirements :

- History of websites visited for each user account and the ability to easily block/allow a site from the history list
- Time of day restrictions on network access (restrict access to specific times of day/week, a maximum amount of time per day, or temporarily block a user for a set period of time or until you unblock them manually)

Apart from these, they have tons of [additional features](http://www.intego.com/mac-parental-control-software#/details)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Premium or Free software is not a problem. I will try this software.

Comment: Sir, I have tried the software, it's great, but it requires another user (**Parent**), is there a software that does not need another superuser's intervention? I mean, with this software, I can set my own user's access time.

Comment: Just like [SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com/index.html)

Comment: @AveMaleficum how about http://anti-social.cc